# Background averaging not working

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, machine-learning, background-subtraction

I'm working on a problem where I'm trying to use background averaging to see what the frame looks like in a beehive behind the bees. I've been trying to use standard averaging (I take an image every 1 or 4 seconds over the course of my 3 hour video) as well as other techniques like mog and mog2. The problem is that there is an extremely high density of bees in the centre that is tightly packed and barely moving, so while I end up with a great view of the background around the middle, the centre turns into a bit of a smear like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on what I could do to improve things? I spoke to a researcher who suggested something called "sparse coding" as one possible options and I'm curious if OpenCV has anything like that or if anyone knows of any other techniques I could try.

Answer (score 1):

I would try techniques related to low-rank approximations of your data $X$. For instance, the paper [GoDec: Randomized Low-rank & Sparse Matrix Decomposition in Noisy Case](http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/41_icmlpaper.pdf) attempts to decompose
$$X = L + S + G$$
with a low-rank part ($\mathrm{rank}(L) \le r$), a sparse part ($\mathrm{card}(S) \le k$) and a residual $G$.

It has been employed for background modeling, with backgrounds related to the low-rank part, plus sparse en independent objects.

[image]

Some video demos are:

- [GoDec and Robust PCA for background modeling on Escalator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpdCvbJI2eg)
- [GoDec and Robust PCA for background modeling on Hall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTrbow8u4Cw)

There are alternatives in the field of robust matrix factorization, and I understand it as an instance of sparse coding.

Answer (score 0):

Why not high pass filter each image before averaging, cutting out the lower frequency (bigger bee than comb)?  Then you should mostly be integrating comb when you average/sum the images

Answer (score 0):

Hey It seems that average really isnt the solution here as at most time a bee captures the background,

If you say that mixture of Gaussians doesnt work , I would have tried 
1. To use visualization to understand a bit more about what I'm trying to find. 
Ill plot the time value of a background pixel and look at a bunch of them

e.g. if your image is built like a [ rows*column*times ]  matrix called timeSeries

```
plot ( timeSeries(i,j,:) ,'.');
```

2. One very simple idea I used is median filtering which works great to remove bright outliers. However in your case you might need to use a smaller percentile on each pixel

something like:

```
bg_img(i,j) = prctile ( timeSerties(i,j,:) , 30 ) ;
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers,
  Elad

Comment: Hi Elad, thanks so much for the advice. I was using masking to cover some of the bright reflective tags I had on the bees when I tried median filtering it didn't make too much of a difference like you had predicted. I tried a few different percentiles too but that middle section stubbornly refuses to do better than a white smear.